# Create a dynamic Folder Path in SSIS Flexible File Destination

Tags: ssis, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to dump data into Azure Datalake Gen2 using SSIS. I found about Flexible File Destination Editor but I am stuck at setting the Folder Path dynamically. I have set the variable thisYear and thisMonth but how do I use those variables in my Folder Path?

I tried as below but it wouldnt give me the expected value of testdump/2021/08. Am I missing something? Please help.
[image]

My full data flow as below:

[image]

Comment: What is the output so far ?

Comment: In my datalake, I will have testdump/@[User::thisYear]/@[User::thisMonth] folder path instead of testdump/2021/08

Comment: what are the values for @[User::thisYear] and @[User::thisMonth] ?

Comment: values for thisYear = 2021 and thisMonth = 08

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it by setting the 'Expressions' in the data flow task
[image]